# Android - How To Block User to Delete App

Tags: android

Is that possible to block user delete app?

Comment: How do think people would feel when Malware could never be uninstalled :)

Comment: Yes its possible [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Comment: @Jacob Could you please link to where in the Device Administration APIs it gives an option to prevent uninstall? I've never heard of this part of the API.

Comment: @RaghavSood It's not part of the API; active device administrators are simply not uninstallable.  However, circumventing this is a simple matter of going into Settings > Security > Device Administrators and unchecking the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible for third party apps for security reasons. This is done so that Malware type apps can be removed.

You may be able to make it harder for the user by installing your app to `/system/app`, but this will require the device to be rooted. And if the device is rooted, the user can simply delete it.

The apps which come preloaded on many OEM devices are installed as part of the ROM on the device, and hence cannot be removed unless you root. They are installed to `/system/app` when the ROM image is built. If you can contact and convince OEMs to include your app in this way, go for it.